# JSON to NSDictionary to NSArray give me empty NSArray ? :(

Tags: ios, json, nsarray, nsdictionary

Here is my problem :

INPUT (from a certain website) :

```
{"error":[],"results":{"count":2,"data":[{"ART_ID":"656","ART_NAME":"Noir D\u00e9sir","ART_PICTURE":".....","NB_ALBUM":"15","NB_FAN":"90176","SMARTRADIO":"1","URL_REWRITING":"noir-desir"},{"ART_ID":"167225","ART_NAME":"LMFAO","ART_PICTURE":"....","NB_ALBUM":"17","NB_FAN":"122408","SMARTRADIO":"1","URL_REWRITING":"lmfao"}],"total":2}}
```

So, once I have that I'm using a few JSON classes :

```
 NSError* jsonError = nil;
 //responseData contains my json feed
 NSDictionary* dict = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:responseData options:0 error:&jsonError];

 NSLog(@"responseDictionary : \n%@\n--------\n", [dict description]);
```

In order to obtain the following :

```
{
    error =     (
    );
    results =     {
        count = 2;
        data =         (
                        {
                "ART_ID" = 656;
                "ART_NAME" = "Noir D\U00e9sir";
                "ART_PICTURE" = 17b0a9c3defcf8c3eef943759606b3f4;
                "NB_ALBUM" = 15;
                "NB_FAN" = 90176;
                SMARTRADIO = 1;
                "URL_REWRITING" = "noir-desir";
            },
                        {
                "ART_ID" = 167225;
                "ART_NAME" = LMFAO;
                "ART_PICTURE" = 72a09b9202da38afae077e80c7598212;
                "NB_ALBUM" = 17;
                "NB_FAN" = 122408;
                SMARTRADIO = 1;
                "URL_REWRITING" = lmfao;
            }
        );
        total = 2;
    };
}
```

Here, I don't really have any problem... But now, I want to get the "data" field in this NSDictionary. So I just create a new one :

```
NSDictionary* resultField = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithDictionary:[dict objectForKey:@"results"]];
```

Wich contains :

```
{
    count = 2;
    data =     (
                {
            "ART_ID" = 656;
            "ART_NAME" = "Noir D\U00e9sir";
            "ART_PICTURE" = 17b0a9c3defcf8c3eef943759606b3f4;
            "NB_ALBUM" = 15;
            "NB_FAN" = 90176;
            SMARTRADIO = 1;
            "URL_REWRITING" = "noir-desir";
        },
                {
            "ART_ID" = 167225;
            "ART_NAME" = LMFAO;
            "ART_PICTURE" = 72a09b9202da38afae077e80c7598212;
            "NB_ALBUM" = 17;
            "NB_FAN" = 122408;
            SMARTRADIO = 1;
            "URL_REWRITING" = lmfao;
        }
    );
    total = 2;
}
```

Now I want to get my "data" field, which now is a JSONArray (not a NSDictionary anymore...) :

```
NSArray* dataField = [[NSArray alloc] initWithArray:[dict objectForKey:@"data"]];
```

But after that my dataField is empty... By that I mean this :

```
NSArray* dataField = [[NSArray alloc] initWithArray:[dict objectForKey:@"data"]];
if (!dataField || ![dataField isKindOfClass:[NSArray class]]) {
    NSLog(@"Pb parsing DATA field as NSArray...");
}
NSLog(@"dataField : \n%@\n--------\n", [dataField description]);
```

Doesn't show me the error since it a correctly formatted NSArray, but prints me the following :

```
2012-02-02 14:08:52.315 myapp[5235:f803] dataField : 
(
)
```

I now am lost, I really don't know what's happening... If you guys have any clue on this issue I'd be glad if you could help me !

Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are taking the "Data" Array from the first dictionary (dict), you should take it from resultField:

```
NSArray* dataField = [[NSArray alloc] initWithArray:[resultField objectForKey:@"data"]];
```

Comment: OMG ! Thank you, I didn't even saw that... Damn copy paste :'(

Comment: saved my 30mins for another issue :)